# webstorm unresolved function or method for npm azure-storage (all azure modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, npm, webstorm

WebStorm IDE having some issues with azure-storage intelligent coding does not find methods for that library (but the code works fine when executed).

[image of unresolved function or method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr2x9.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, some issues for code completion or highlight hint not always mean the code exists errors, especially for Dynamic Language like JavaScript.

I tried to reproduce your issues, and I found some interesting things.

After I writed the code `var azureStorage = require('azure-storage')`, the code completion for the symbol `azureStorage` could not display the function suggestions for azure-storage module. WebStorm regard the varable `azureStorage` as a  normal object, see below.

[image]

However, the code completion for any undeclared symbol will display all functions of all modules depended on the project after I commented the code `var azureStorage = require('azure-storage')`, see below. It seems that WebStorm default bind all functions of all modules with undeclared symbols automatically.

[image]

Although we can use the code completion in this way, the require code must be required when the code works.

For more details about `Auto-completing code`, you can refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/auto-completing-code.html.

Comment: wow, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for your detailed explanation!